# Display list of subtasks and corresponding stories inside an Epic

Tags: jira, jql

I want to list all Stories and Subtask of an existing epic ES-1 in project ES. Is there a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not possible with the out-of-the-box JQL capabilities of Jira. However, if you have ScriptRunner at hand, you could try:

```
key = ES-1 OR "Epic Link" = ES-1 OR issueFunction in subtasksOf("'Epic Link' = ES-1") ORDER BY type ASC
```